# Adolf Hitler using the technology in the phone to win a war?

Tags: plot-explanation, misfits

In the television series, Misfits, S03E04, how did Adolf Hitler actually use the technology present in the cell phone to win the war?

Comment: Seeing this question I am glad I stopped watching Misfits at 3x01. It just wasnt the same great show anymore. :/

Comment: I think you just happened to miss the point. This seemed to me more of a _butterfly effect_ than actually "using the technology". We could indeed say that the Nazi scientists, who were geniuses, actually studied the cellphone and came up with something. However, I saw this moment more as a butterfly effect where simply leaving the cellphone behind had some major consequences in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was never made clear in the episode, as to which specific technology found in a cell phone, was used by Nazis to win the war, I would like to believe that they exploited cell phones for better communication, which would have helped them in efficient diversion of resources to the places they need. It's pure speculation on my part, since nothing conclusive has been presented in the concerned episode.